# What docs/tutorials/guides are there that a Kohana newbie should know about?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

As a former CodeIgniter user, I would really like to migrate to another framework. My options were FuelPHP or Kohana, and as Fuel isn't there yet what docs/tutorials/guides i should know about that could help me get up to speed?

I am aware about their docs but they are not so great, for example i can't seem to find anything related to how to use the Session class, how to configure it to use the database driver, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/4691/resources-for-learning-kohana

There are some resources to learning 3.0.x and lower. I would check out this url for 3.1:

http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/8024/kohana-v3.1.0-released

3.1 and 3.0.x are very similar and you can use the 3.0.x docs to learn 3.1, but I would make sure you see whats difference. The API isn't completely the same.